# How to hide or not to load UIPickerView on uiView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have made a view named inputBox with textBox UiPickerView and segmentControl on it. I am using this control two times to input name for folder generation and then file generation purpose.

For folder name I want to show this inputBox without uipickerview and segmentcontrol while for file i want to use both of them to input name and dimensions for cavas for drawing by using uipickerview. How can I prevent uipickerView to not to be drawn while using for folder name purpose. I can hide it as `picker.hidden=yes;` but i want to not to draw or to be add on sub view.
I can use `picker.release;` 
But I don't want to use it because I have enabled ARC, so need alternative of this.

Comment: you can say that i want to show some selected views of any uiview on another view and remaining on different view.hope this will help to understand.

Comment: Just a side note, `picker.relase` has nothing to do with hiding or showing view. Its purely memory related method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [picker removefromsuperview]; and it worked.